# A Q/A website for NLP

Tags: discussion

I am new in this community, in fact I was looking for a Question and Answering website for Natural Language Processing. I have a master degree in artificial intelligence and am familiar with NLP but not much with Linguistics.
However I like linguistics too

My question is where can I find a Q/A website for NLP? Can I use this community for my pupose?

And finally, I have proposed such a website in the [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) and the direct link for it is [Natural Language Processing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77238/natural-language-processing?referrer=42cN65TLF7HKpsLy4F0Mtw2).

If you are interested please follow my proposal

Comment: There was an old proposal for an NLP site. This was the conclusion: http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/16/merge-with-natural-language-processing/

Comment: I proposed an NLP SE on area 51 a few months ago, got closed: "too much overlap with existing SE".

Comment: For a topic with "too much overlap" there are damn few questions on the existing sites. It might look like there's plenty to a naive observer but to people who know the field you can search for terms and find very few hits for key concepts such as "parse forests"! Still I keep asking questions both here and on SO and I work to curate the relevant tags too. I would support your proposal but it has been nixed already by somebody who I bet doesn't know how dire the situation is for this field on SO.

Comment: My proposal was closed as duplicate of Data Science, it seems a community named Data Science exist which can handle the field better than StackOverflow and Linguistics http://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Ahmad Have you seen my answer?

Comment: @Ahmad: The Data science site seems to cover machine learning, which your proposal also covered. For me, that's not what NLP is about, it's just one of the tools you can use to do NLP with. I wouldn't've included it in your proposal since SE mods who don't know the fields may have closed your proposal because Data science covers machine learning even though it doesn't seem to cover NLP very well at all from what I can see.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that few questions on NLP are asked on this site (still the majority on all SE sites), doesn't mean that we don't allow them. Simply many people are not sure about asking here, and you did well to ask. :)

Anyway, **NLP questions are on topic on this site**, of course, and you are free to ask them on here. The only thing you are supposed to abide by are the usual rules for questions across all SE sites, i.e. scoped, good wording, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, as you said some are hesitated to ask NLP questions here, it seems they find Data Science a better site for such question, if these two site has overlap you can resolve it, however I think the NLP question which more inclined to linguistics could be asked here

Comment: @Ahmad I doubt that's the reason, since the site seems to be fairly recent. We always had users asking whether they could ask here. :)

Comment: If LinguisticsSE wants to get out of beta and into some usefulness for other SE users, we'd better not just allow but encourage CL/NLP questions here, with cross-references as broadly as we can manage. That **is** the role of language, and linguistics, after all. If it be objected that not everybody knows about CL/NLP, then we should learn. It's clearly the future of linguistics. If there be one.

Comment: @jlawler How do you suggest encouraging them?

Comment: "Them"? Who them? And why should I want to encourage them? I view L.SE(beta) as extremely beta, and likely to stay that way indefinitely without structural changes.

Comment: @jlawler You said "we'd better not just allow but encourage CL/NLP questions". I was referring to that. :)

Comment: I think we'd do better to get many more professionals to care, and that's probly only gonna happen if we go over to CL/NLP, which is, as I've been saying for decades, the future of linguistics. If there is any.

Comment: I agree that we should encourage such questions, but the problem is how.